Posting product in a view
Why can I not save images in a folder when I'm creating a product?
This is the controller:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Product pro, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/assets/ProductImage/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            pro.Image = fileName;
        }

        db.Products.Add(pro);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(pro);
}

And this is the view:
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
         <div class="row">
             @foreach (var produkti in Model)
             {
                 <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                     <div class="single-popular-items mb-50 text-center">
                         <div class="popular-img">
                             <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/ProductImage/" + produkti.Image)"     alt="Product Image" />
                             <div class="img-cap">
                                 <span>Add to cart</span>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="popular-caption">
                             <h3><a href="product_details.html">@produkti.Name</a></h3>
                             <span>@produkti.Price</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             }
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

Other details are showing (Name, Price), just the image isn't...
I have tried changing the path... Inserting image from C:// to folder etc..

Please be clear if there is a problem with saving the files, or with displaying them after they were (successfully) saved. Check the destination folder on the device/server to see if any files were added there. Besides that, the View is for a Model that is a collection of objects, but the Controller method that you show uses only a single Model object, so the two do not belong together. That does not help us in finding a cause or a solution.

Hello, the images are not being saved in Folder..

Are there any errors at the line file.SaveAs(path);, if so which? What is in path at that point? Does your server process have Write Access to that location?

Which version of asp.net are you using? Could you please explain? I cannot see the Form Post operation the view you have had shared.

Hello guys , I fixed , the problem was that in Create.cshtml I didn't have the post method
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Department", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

I added this now it is saving
Thanks for helping me,
Best of luck
